# Pandas calculate the number of times there is X sec difference between consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I am trying to count the number of times per `id, date` the `datetime` is different from the previous row by 10 seconds.

**data**

```
id      timestamp      datetime          date           
1       1496660340  2019-06-05 10:59:00  2019-06-05
1       1496660340  2019-06-05 10:59:10  2019-06-05 
1       1496660355  2019-06-05 10:59:40  2019-06-05 <- 30 sec diff from above, so not counted

1       1496655555  2019-06-06 11:58:00  2019-06-06     
1       1496666666  2019-06-06 11:58:10  2019-06-06     
1       1496666677  2019-06-06 11:58:20  2019-06-06 

2       1496655555  2019-06-05 11:58:00  2019-06-05     
2       1496666666  2019-06-05 11:58:10  2019-06-05     
2       1496666677  2019-06-05 11:58:20  2019-06-05     

Data columns (total 4 columns):
       id              int64
     timestamp         int64
     datetime          datetime64[ns]
      date              object
```

**Desired**

```
id         date      num_count
1       2019-06-05      1
1       2019-06-06      2
2       2019-06-05      2
```

**what i've tried**

```
# get all the time differences first
df['timediff'] = df.groupby(['id','date'])['datetime'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 's')

#Count the number of 10sec differences
x = pd.DataFrame(df[df['timediff']==10].groupby(['id','date'],as_index=False)['timediff'].count())
```

Thing is im not sure if this is the right way. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom function with `groupby`:

```
def difference_condition(x):
    return x.diff().dt.total_seconds().eq(10).sum()

res = df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['datetime'].apply(difference_condition)

print(res.reset_index(name='count'))

   id       date  count
0   1 2019-06-05      1
1   1 2019-06-06      2
2   2 2019-06-05      2
```

**Setup**

```
from io import StringIO

x = """id|timestamp|datetime|date
1       |1496660340  |2019-06-05 10:59:00  |2019-06-05
1       |1496660340  |2019-06-05 10:59:10  |2019-06-05 
1       |1496660355  |2019-06-05 10:59:40  |2019-06-05
1       |1496655555  |2019-06-06 11:58:00  |2019-06-06     
1       |1496666666  |2019-06-06 11:58:10  |2019-06-06     
1       |1496666677  |2019-06-06 11:58:20  |2019-06-06 
2       |1496655555  |2019-06-05 11:58:00  |2019-06-05     
2       |1496666666  |2019-06-05 11:58:10  |2019-06-05     
2       |1496666677  |2019-06-05 11:58:20  |2019-06-05"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), sep='|')
df[['datetime', 'date']] = df[['datetime', 'date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: im getting zeros in my count, are you suppose to add a parameter to the function `difference_condition(x)` in the third line?

Comment: Is your dtype the same as mine? Ive updated my question to reflect my dtype.

Comment: @jxn, I've added my setup which you can copy-paste to confirm.

Comment: somehow only after i modified your function to fillna to zeros and convert float to integers do i get the count. `def difference_condition(x):
    return x.diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0).astype(int).eq(10).sum()` because `dt.total_seconds()` transforms my data to float

Comment: @jxn, I see, there must be some issue with your data. Because with the sample you've provided it works.

Comment: Yea your method works fine when i tested. its weird :S Thanks for your help!